# How to check the 'Advanced Share' permissions on a folder using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, directory, access-control, shared-directory

Hi I want to check if a particular folder is shared with a user.
for the normal share rights, I can the info by

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    DirectorySecurity acl = di.GetAccessControl(AccessControlSections.All);
    AuthorizationRuleCollection rules = acl.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(NTAccount));

    //Go through the rules returned from the DirectorySecurity
    foreach (AuthorizationRule rule in rules)
    {
        //If we find one that matches the identity we are looking for
        if (rule.IdentityReference.Value.Equals(NtAccountName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            //Cast to a FileSystemAccessRule to check for access rights
            if ((((FileSystemAccessRule)rule).FileSystemRights & FileSystemRights.WriteData) > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} has write access to {1}", NtAccountName, path));
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} does not have write access to {1}", NtAccountName, path));
            }
        }
    }
```

But the problem with this approach is that the if shared the folder using the "Advanced Share" option, as shown in image, it doesn't show any entry into the log.

How to calculate it?

[image: advanced Share with a user]

Comment: Finally, did you obtain the answer? I need to do the same.